# Subsets of Cartesian products are not usually products?

Tags: calculus

My book says that subsets of products are not usually products and gives the following explanation:

The subset $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$ of $\mathbb R^2$ is not a product.

I couldn't understand this statement properly. Isn't $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$ the product of the intervals : $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ in $\mathbb R?$

Thanks a lot for reading.

**( I started reading Mathematics after a long gap because of work reasons. Apologize if my question is too trivial. )**

Comment: Your set consists of two points. A more visual example would be a disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I couldn't understand this statement properly. Isn't $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$ the product of the intervals : $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ in $\mathbb R?$

The "interval" $(1,0)$ doesn't make sense, unless you meant the set consisting of (only) the real numbers $0$ and $1$ but in that case the order doesn't matter and you then have with $X=\left\{0,1\right\}$:
$$X \times X = \left\{(a,b) \;\vert\; a \in X, b \in X\right\} = \left\{\color{red}{(0,0)},\color{blue}{(0,1)},\color{blue}{(1,0)},\color{red}{(1,1)}\right\}$$
which isn't the same as $\left\{\color{blue}{(0,1)},\color{blue}{(1,0)}\right\}$.

If you actually meant the **interval** $(0,1)$ (*open*) or $[0,1]$ (*closed*), then note that for example:
$$(0,1) \times (0,1) = \left\{(a,b) \;\vert\; a \in (0,1), b \in (0,1)\right\}$$
which also contains elements such as $(0.5,0.3)$ because $0< 0.5 < 1$ and $0< 0.3 < 1$.

---

Above I showed that $\{(\color{green}{0},\color{purple}{1}), (\color{green}{1},\color{purple}{0})\}$ isn't the same as the product $\left\{0,1\right\} \times \left\{0,1\right\}$, but perhaps you wonder if it *is* equal to some *other* product $\color{green}{A} \times \color{purple}{B}$. This isn't possible since:

- $\color{green}{A}$ would need to contain at least $\color{green}{0}$ and $\color{green}{1}$;
- $\color{purple}{B}$ would need to contain at least $\color{purple}{1}$ and $\color{purple}{0}$;

but then $A \times B$ automatically contains $\color{red}{(0,0)}$ and $\color{red}{(1,1)}$ too.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also please explain why the above subset is not a product?

Comment: Take a look at how products are defined and then take the example of $\left\{0,1\right\} \times \left\{0,1\right\}$; you do not only get the blue elements (which you want), but the red ones too.

Comment: I added a paragraph to address the question whether that set could be _some other cartesian product_.

Comment: So $\{ (0,1), (1,0)\}$ is not a product because the product of $\mathbb R^2$ should include infinite combinations of $\mathbb R \times  \mathbb R$. Is that correct?

Comment: The notation "$\{ {0,1}×{0,1}\}$" does not makes sense and I can't really tell what you meant. In any case, the cartesian $A \times B$ contains **all** elements of the form $(a,b)$, with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ independently.

Comment: I have edited it. please have a look again

Comment: An argument for why $\{ (0,1), (1,0)\}$ is not a product, is the last paragraph of my answer (which I added later). The cartesian product $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ contains _way more_ elements, such as $(\pi,-\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: thank you !!    $~~~$

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not the product of intervals $(0,1)$, and $(1,0)$. First of all, $(1,0)$ is not an interval, because if $(a,b)$ is an interval, we assume $ a < b$. Here, Cartesian product of two sets $A$ and $B$, denoted by $A\times B$, is the set of all elements of the form $(a,b), a \in A \ ,b \in B$. So, here for example, $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ would contain the element $(0.5,0.5)$, since $0.5 \in (0,1)$. But your set doesn't have this element. Hope it clears your doubt, if you still have doubt feel free to ask in comments.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also please explain why the above subset is not a product?

Comment: See, assume the set is a product $A\times B$. Then, the set $B$ must have atleast $0$ and $1$ (actually it should have only $0$ and $1$) because in the elements of your set, the 2nd coordinates are $1$ and $0$ respectively. Similarily, the set $A$ must also contain $0$ and $1$. But then, $A\times B$ should have 4 elements, while your set has 2 elements

Comment: Thank you very much !!!